# Elementary Definition of Differentiability: What's Correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

In most if not all elementary calculus books, a function $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is said to be "differentiable'' at a point $a \in A$ if and only if the limit
$$
\textrm{lim}_{h \rightarrow 0}\,\,\, \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}
$$
exists, and in which the value of this limit is denoted $f'(a)$.

The problem is, basic statements such as...

"If $f$, $g$ are differentiable at $a$, then $f + g$ is differentiable at $x = a$ and $(f + g)'(a) = f'(a) + g'(a)$."

...or such as...

"If $g$ is differentiable at $a$, and $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, then $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $(f \circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$."

...are false under this definition.

One can fix the first statement by adding some assumption about the compatibility of the domains of $f$ and $g$ (e.g., that $a$ not be an isolated point of dom $f$ $\cap$ dom $g$, or that dom $f$, dom $g$ both be open), and likewise one can fix the second statement by adding some ad-hoc small print (that $a$ not be an isolated point of dom $f \circ g$, or that dom $f$ be open, or that $g(a)$ be an interior point of dom $f$, etc). But I'm wondering if the "correct" fix shouldn't be to alter the definition of differentiability to make the above statements automatically correct, with no added small print. Specifically, require as part of the definition of differentiability that $a$ be in the interior of $\textrm{dom}\,\, f$, i.e., that $f$ be defined in a neighbourhood of $a$. (E.g., under this definition *no* function of domain $[0, \infty)$ would be "differentiable" at $x = 0$.)

Have people seen this definition in use, or seen this point debated? What are people's opinion on this?

And what are the conventions in higher dimensions, i.e., for functions $f : A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: A function is differentiable at a only if it is continuous at a.  I think that that should take care of the rest of your issues.

Comment: "...are false under this definition." : what makes you think it is ?

Comment: @Doug M. Not really :) Those statements in quotes are still false under the definition given at the top :)

Comment: @user195... For the first statement, take $f$, $g$ to be respectively the indicator functions of $[0, \infty)$, $(-\infty, 0]$, $a = 0$. For the second statement, take $f(x) = x^{3/2}$, $g(x) = -x^2$, $a = 0$.

Comment: In most contexts,  an open set containing the point $a$ is a subset of $dom  (f)$ and of dom (g), and it is assumed that dom (f+g)=dom (f)\cap dom(g)$. It is possible that $dom (f)\cap dom (g)=\{a\}.$

Comment: with you first definition, $1_{[0,\infty[}(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. if you want a definition including the case $a$ being an extremum  point of the domain of definition of $f$, then you have to be careful with $f+g$, yes. so what ? (note that $f+g$ is not defined in the neighborhood of $a$ if $dom(f) \cap dom(g) = \{a\}$)

Comment: For the first statement, take f, g to be respectively the indicator functions of [0,∞), (−∞,0]... f,g are neither continuous nor differentiable at 0.... $f(x) = x^3/2, g=-x^2...$ f(g(x)) is undefined as a real-valued function.  If f is a function from the reals to the complex numbers $(d/dx) f(g(x)) = (df/dg)(dg/dx) = -3x^2 i$, and (d/dx) f(g(0)) = 0.

Comment: @Doug M, @user1952009: Sorry guys, screwed up my examples. When I wrote ``$1_{[0,\infty)}$'' I meant (in the privacy of my head) the function that is 0 on $[0,\infty)$ and that is undefined on $(-\infty, 0)$. (This function can also be used as $f$ in my counterexample for the chain rule by the way, in replacement of $x^{3/2}$.) Same for $1_{(-\infty, 0]}$. Hopefully now things should make more sense.

Comment: @Labrador at this point I have forgotten what these examples were supposed to show. I still don't see a problem with "if f'(x) and g'(x) are defined at a then (f+g)'(a) = f'(a) + g'(a)" or d/dx f(g(x)) = df/dg dg/dx

Comment: @Doug M: It's really simple: if $f$ has domain $[0,\infty)$ and $g$ has domain $(-\infty, 0]$ then you may have a case where $f'(0)$ exists, $g'(0)$ exists, but $(f + g)'(0)$ does not exist. [Actually, $(f + g)'(0)$ will definitely not exist, since dom$(f + g) = \{0\}$.] A similar "counterexample" to the chain rule can be easily made up.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it is rarely stated clearly, but I think the common assumption when talking about derivatives is that the functions are defined on an open neighborhood of a, as you suggest. I think in most calculus books, they assume adding too many details will confuse students so they leave it out.

I'm taking a light complex analysis class that's aimed at engineers right now, and I'm often frustrated by the professor's unwillingness to use terms like "open set" that are really important parts of definitions of terms we're using. Oftentimes professors do things in the hope of simplifying things that, in my opinion, actually make them more complicated.

Edit: As evidence that this practice is common, in Wikipedia's definition of the derivative they start with this:

"Let f be a real valued function defined in an open neighborhood of a real number a."

Comment: replacing "open sets" by $]b,c[$ is preferable at least in a first time...

Comment: That's a good point. The word "neighborhood" is also a bit friendlier than "open set".

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know that I'm not crazy :)